# What version of Ubuntu should i install on a old computer that is supposed to run Windows Vista?

Tags: versions

I have a computer that used to run Windows Vista Business Version, but it currently runs Windows 10. I want to install ubuntu on it, but I dont know which version to install. Also, I am extremely new to Ubuntu.

Comment: I use a 2005 HP Compaq in my QA testing of Ubuntu and *flavors*, ie. a box in the era of windows XP, however the OS the machine came with is **not** a good indicator of the machine specs, your best bet is to work out what hardware the box contains OR Try the system in *live* mode on your actual hardware and decide for yourself. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install  (which applies to all flavors too).  Your graphic card/GPU may dictate some *flavors* are better than others for really old hardware

Comment: FYI: The release of of Ubuntu, eg. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, primarily tell you the *year.month* of release, ie. **22.04** tells you it was the 2022-April release, the **LTS** that it's a *long-term-support* release, and **Desktop** tells you it contains a GUI or graphical desktop rather than being text only (Server) system. Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop tells you it was the 2023-October release or a newer system, but with a shorter life as it isn't a long-term-support (LTS) release; ie. newer software stack is included.

Comment: I have some *old* hardware that will perform better with the GA kernel stack due to graphics hardware (ie. 5.15 kernel) thus don't perform as well with 23.10 with the 6.5 kernel, nor Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Desktop which also uses the 6.5 kernel... They'll however run fine if using 22.04 with the GA kernel stack (ie. older 5.15 kernel stack) or specific desktops are used (so even the release 22.04 isn't the whole picture) but will also perform fine with some desktops with 6.5 kernel.. this is a GPU specific issue, where you gave no details as to your actual hardware.  Testing is a good way to know.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors) My old XP era laptop with 1.5GB  RAM would not install Ubuntu, but did install both server version & Kubuntu. but using  external SSD with that system  made it very functional. The old internal HDD was going to swap a lot if I tried to load more than one larger app like Firefox, and it was slow. SSD only slightly paused with swap. and was a lot faster overall.